# application which allows me to share data onto to FB wall as link

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here's what I am actually trying.
I created a task using Producteev. and shared this on FBwall. 
my friends can view it and comment.
Would it be possible to use graph api create an application that will allow me to share data from the application onto FB.

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 0):

Try [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/), which encapsulates everything you are looking for. If you are only interested in facebook, then you will want to remove references to the other services. But it's easy to include this into you program, and I recommend you try it to see how it works.

You will need to provide some application ID information to initialize it for facebook. go the the facebook developers site and obtain those.

Comment: Do I have to like the app to be able to publish a feed on my wall?